# Scroll height to hide menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have this code to hide and show menu when scroll. How can i do it to appear class only of scroll >= than 500px. I have traied to ad a if (scroll >= 500) on code but it wont work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
// console.log($);

       var lastScrollTop = 200;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('nav').addClass('nav-off');
        $('nav').removeClass('nav-on');
    } else {
        $('nav').addClass('nav-on');
        $('nav').removeClass('nav-off');
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code Show Button while Scroll down more than 500px
When Scroll up it hide,
Hope its help

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFBsQ.png)
[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYG8U.png)

```
var offset = 500
    $(window).on('load scroll', function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('body nav').addClass('nav-on');
        $('body nav').removeClass('nav-off');

    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < offset) {
        $('body nav').removeClass('nav-on');
        $('body nav').addClass('nav-off');


    }

});

var lastScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > lastScroll) {
        $('body nav').removeClass('up');
        $('body nav').addClass('down');

    } else if (scrollTop < lastScroll) {
        $('body nav').addClass('up');
        $('body nav').removeClass('down');
    } else {

    }
    lastScroll = scrollTop;
});
```

Your CSS would be using the same

```
nav.nav-off {
    top: -120px;
    background: transparent;
}

nav.nav-on {
    top: 0;
}
```

and you could put two more for up and down for

```
nav.down {
  
}

nav.up {
   
}
```

Comment: almost... it won't stay menu visible until 900px, hand adds class remove on the moment i start scroll see it live: [https://www.bakar.store/producto/purple-coral_all-day-long/]

Comment: hey you add nav-off in body instead of the nav

Comment: The code is change, but the thing is that the scroll = 0 should only work after the 500px scroll down, and with this solution the class changes when i scrooll down.

The menu until 500px should stay fixed on scroll down and up and only after scroll 500px it applys the nav on/off effect

Comment: hey ,can you show me the demo site of the code implement inside

Comment: here it is: https://www.bakar.store/clothing/ Now .up and .down don't have css code, but when i start scroll down= 0 adds class

Comment: the first part of code should handled this problem

Comment: please check this site , it use the above code of mine [link](https://shorturl.at/dkQ57)

Comment: var offset = 500 mean  scroll down more than 500px after that its add 'nav-on'

Comment: lastScroll  is check whether the user scroll is large or small than the previous to determine the scroll up and down

Answer (score 0):

last part of the code note working it overtakes 1'st part, and wont respect the 500px min height to add class.

This is the part that wont let the other to work. if i deleat it it only works at 500ps to show and to hide. The scroll to top part only should wolt when you scroll down 500px.

```
var lastScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scrollTop > lastScroll) {
    $('body').addClass('nav-on');
    $('body').removeClass('nav-off');
} else if (scrollTop < lastScroll) {
    $('body').removeClass('nav-on');
    $('body').addClass('nav-off');
} else {

}
lastScroll = scrollTop;
});
```